# iframe not scrolling in iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe, safari

I am having trouble in scrolling of iframe. I am using safari and my iOS version is 8.3. Problem is that when i use iframe in simple html page i.e. just iframe element with one parent div it works fine everywhere (Even in iOS). But when i use same code inside my website it doesn't work. I tried adding important in CSS also it is clear from inspect elements that no other CSS is overriding CSS of iframe. I tried with different variation of CSS (like overflow:auto, setting style and inserting parent div using JavaScript) but nothing seems to work. Here is the link of page [Page](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93241685/Reservations%20_%20Henderson%20Pet%20Resort.html)

Comment: The link in your post is broken and you haven't included the code in your question.

Comment: Hi Fenton! This was posted in 2016 and since then dropbox changes it's public link structure.

Comment: Also I do not have that code with me now. As problem was resolved in an other way.

Comment: What was the way? So others can know.